# Understanding a Cobweb code

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to run a cobweb code in Mathematica and I need the following script:

```
ClearAll[CobwebPlot]
Options[CobwebPlot]=Join[{CobStyle->Automatic},Options[Graphics]];
CobwebPlot[f_,start_?NumericQ,n_,xrange:{xmin_,xmax_},opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=Module[{cob,x,g1,coor},
cob=NestList[f,N[start],n];
coor = Partition[Riffle[cob,cob],2,1];
coor[[1,2]]=0;
cobstyle=OptionValue[CobwebPlot,CobStyle];
cobstyle=If[cobstyle===Automatic,Red,cobstyle];
g1=Graphics[{cobstyle,Line[coor]}];
Show[{Plot[{x,f[x]},{x,xmin,xmax},PlotStyle->{{Thick,Black},Black}],g1},FilterRules[{opts},Options[Graphics]]]
]

Manipulate[CobwebPlot[Sqrt[3#-1]&,\[Alpha],40,{0,5},PlotRange->{{0,4.5},{0,3.65}},Frame->True,Axes->False,CobStyle->Directive[Dashed,Red],PlotRangePadding->None],{\[Alpha],0.5,4.375}]
```

I found the script online but I don't understand some features, such as what is the purpose of the following characters, **#** and **&**, in the **Manipulate[]** segment of the code:

```
Manipulate[CobwebPlot[Sqrt[3#-1]&,\[Alpha],40,{0,5},PlotRange->{{0,4.5},{0,3.65}},Frame->True,Axes->False,CobStyle->Directive[Dashed,Red],PlotRangePadding->None],{\[Alpha],0.5,4.375}]
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this Mathematica documentation page on pure functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html), or what other languages call [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), or lambda functions.

---

To give a cute example, suppose you have the function

```
doItTwice[x_,f_] := f[f[x]];
```

Now say you want to use this function to square the number seven twice. One way to do this would be to define a square function like this:

```
square[x_] := x^2; 
doItTwice[7, square]
```

Well, there is a cleaner way to do this by simply writing the square function as a pure function, which would look like `(#^2)&`. The `#` is the parameter to the pure function, and the `&` is just there to indicate that it's a pure function. Really the parenthesis aren't even necessary, so you could write `#^2&`. Anyways, the following code is now a cleaner way to square seven twice:

```
doItTwice[7, (#^2)&]
```